# Can CodeDom create optional arguments when generating a c# method?

Tags: c#, .net, codedom

Can CodeDom create optional arguments when generating a c# method and provide a default value?

For example:

```
public void ExampleMethod(int required
                          , string optionalstr = "default string"
                          , int optionalint = 10)
```

---

**Solution**
I've found a simple workaround for this, you can just put the default value in as part of the argument name:

```
CodeParameterDeclarationExpression(typeof(int), "optionalint = 5");
```

This works for me b/c I'm only using the CodeDom to produce C# code.  It won't work if you need to support multiple languages.

Comment: Note that just because you can do this doesn't mean it's a good idea :)

Comment: I'm surprised that that doesn't give an error.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

Add the `[Optional]` attribute.
To specify the default value, add the `[[DefaultParameterValue(...)]` attribute.  (If the default value is `0` or `null`, this attribute can be omitted.

I wrote a [more detailed explanation](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/01/optional-parameters-in-c-4.html) on my blog.

Comment: Can I provide a default value?  (Just updated the question for more details about this)  I'd like to give a string value (for example) a default value instead of it just passing null.

Comment: @Not: Yes.  Add the `[DefaultParameterValue]` attribute.

Comment: Yep, those work, thanks.  Resharper doesn't like it though =( I wish there was a way to make it output in the , int optional = 5) format.

Comment: @Not: That's a bug in Resharper.  You should report it.